# PHP Multiples inserts on sql server scalar variable

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm running an operation where php reads 480k different infos from an external API and stores it on a sql server db

It is taking near 2h to complete the operation, and the most time consuming part is SQL Server

Insert into scalar variable @table should be faster than inserting into table, and then insert it into table from @table after a bunch of inserts

Can I declare @table with sqlsrv_query/mssql_query, and use @table on a different sqlsrv_query/mssql_query statement under the same connection?

This would be the standard aproach

```
foreach (...) {
    sqlsrv_query($connection, "INSERT INTO mytable () VALUES ()")
}
```

This is what I'm doing now, since there is only one input on mytable and it is a large table, indexes are computed only once

```
$qry = "DECLARE @mytable TABLE (...)\n";
foreach (...) {
    $qry .= "INSERT INTO @mytable () VALUES ()\n";
}
$qry .= "INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM @mytable\n";
sqlsrv_query($connection, $qry)
```

This is what I would like to do to avoid large query errors

```
sqlsrv_query($connection, "DECLARE @mytable TABLE (...)");
foreach (...) {
    sqlsrv_query($connection, "INSERT INTO @mytable () VALUES ()")
}
sqlsrv_query($connection, "INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM @mytable")
```

Is it possible?

Comment: show us some code? What are you doing? not sure why you think insert into @table is faster.

Comment: Triggers and Indicies may slow down injection.  Rather than a table variable, I would suggest staging table.  Furthermore, not a PHP guy, but it sounds like you could benefit from SQLBulkCopy.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/default-php-data-types , there is no support for table-valued parameter on PHP.

Comment: Guys I edited the post to add some code as asked.
I'm sure BULK INSERT would be a good option, but I have network issues among php linux server and sqlsrv win server